# Removing a 1px gap in Outlook 2013-2016

Tags: outlook, html-email, vml

I am trying to get rid of a 1px gap at the far right of a vml graphic that appears in Outlook 2010, 2013, 2016.

I understand that Outlook adds `<p></p>` automatically to the bottom of the xml, which is why I zeroed out the font-size and the line-height, which fixes the gap at the bottom. Any suggestions on what else might be automatically added that might add the space?

```
<xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v"/>
  <v:polyline style="width: 500px; 24px; display: inline-block; padding-right: 0pt; border: 0pt !important;" fillcolor="#563d82" strokecolor="#563d82" strokeweight="0pt" stroke="false" coordorigin="0 0" coordsize="24 500" v:borderrightcolor="#ff0000" points="0pt,24pt, 500pt,24pt, 500pt,0pt, 0pt,24pt">
  </v:polyline>
</xml>
```

Full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" width="498" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0pt !important; margin: 0pt; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
        <tr align="right">
          <td align="right" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0; mso-margin-top-alt: 0pt; mso-margin-bottom-alt: 0px; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; display: inline-block;">
            <xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v"/>
            <v:polyline style="width: 500px; 24px; display: inline-block; padding-right: 0pt; border: 0pt !important;" fillcolor="#563d82" strokecolor="#563d82" strokeweight="0pt" stroke="false" coordorigin="0 0" coordsize="24 500" v:borderrightcolor="#ff0000" points="0pt,24pt, 500pt,24pt, 500pt,0pt, 0pt,24pt">
            </v:polyline>
            </xml>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table bgcolor="#563d82" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <p class="footerlink" style="padding: 0px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px; text-align: left;">Placeholder text.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I should add this html is only visible in Outlook. I have a css graphic that covers every other browser. Too bad that doesn't work with Outlook.

Comment: outlook uses word for its html rendering engine, and word's html rendering is so bad you'd be better off using the ultra-modern "telnet to port 80" browser to render sites.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the two tables for right alignment fixes the 1px gap on the far right.

```
<div align="right" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
  <xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v"/>
    <v:polyline fillcolor="#563d82" strokeweight="0pt" stroke="false" strokecolor="#563d82" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" points="0pt,25pt 500pt,25pt 500pt,0pt 0pt,25pt"></v:polyline>
  </xml>
</div>
```

This fixes the alignment issue for Outlook 2016 and Windows 10 Mail, but it leaves a hairline white line between the vml graphic and the table for Outlook 2010 and 2013. I have tried adding css and table borders, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Since this answer doesn't fully answer your original question, can I suggest that you update your question with this progress and delete this answer?